# how to check that any of the button is clicked or not in iphone application

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton

I have six button i want that user must select any of the six button before moving to next screen if it does not select any then it should not move to next screen I have read to use BOOL flag but this show which button is clicked i want that if any of the six buttons is clicked then user can move to next screen

```
-(IBAction)locationOneButtonAction{
    // your stuff
    _flag = YES;
  }
 -(IBAction)locationTwoButtonAction{
// your stuff
_flag = YES;
 }
```

Comment: What is your problem than ? You can check _flag value as if it is YES than allow move to next screen else not.

Comment: it is ok my problem is that i have question with six button options user need to select any of the one if does not selct any one then it shoud give alert

Comment: @Jennis why you downvoted i expalined problem to you

Comment: I have not downvoted. Though you can't blame any one for that as this is very simple question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution this problem is to declare a bool for your class (let's say it is called "ClickViewController" like (so at the top)

```
@interface ClickViewController () {
   bool wasClicked;
}
...
-(IBAction)locationOneButtonAction{
// your stuff
   wasClicked = YES;
}
```

Then when the button that should move to the next page is clicked utilize a method like this.

```
-(void)nextPageClicked{
   if (wasClicked){
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender: self];
   } else {
      // do something else here, like tell the user why you didn't move them
   }
}
```

This means that you cannot draw the segue from the button to the next view.  If you are using storyboards, this means that you can't draw the segue from the button that is supposed to move it to the next view, rather you should draw it from the view controller icon to the next view.  Then select the segue, name it, and use the method above with the name.

I'm also not sure if you mean that you want each of the buttons to move to the next view, if that is the case, you can use basically the same code, but just put the code [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender: self]; line in action for the button.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Just saw your new comment, the last code snippet and paragraphs are probably the most relevant to you then.

Answer (score 0):

Intially add BOOL _flag; int curIndex; in .h file.

Now add intially  _flag = FALSE; in viewDidLoad method as it indicate no button clicked.

Make userInteractionEnabled for each button to be able to click and add tag to each button.

Now in action method of each click of button do this:

```
(IBAction)locationOneButtonAction:(id)sender{
   curIndex = [sender tag]; //which button clicked
   // your stuff
   _flag = TRUE;
}
-(IBAction)locationTwoButtonAction{
curIndex = [sender tag]; //which button clicked
// your stuff
_flag = YES;
}
........
........
```

Now check like this if button clicked:

```
if(_flag)
{
   NSLog(@"Button clicked with tag: %d",curIndex);
}
else
{
  NSLog(@"Not any Button clicked");
}
```